# Send CSRF token with laravel header() method

Tags: laravel, csrf

Is it possible to protect post method with `CSRF` token with laravel `header()` method ?
just like

```
$obj->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Comment: yes it's possible by creating middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Answer (score 1):

Every routes register within your app in the `web.php` file by default is already protect by the `VerifyCsrfToken`. In the `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` the method `mapWebRoutes` attach on every routes in the `web.php` file the `web` middleware which is a wrapper of many middleware like you can see in the `App\Http\Kernel` class

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // others middlewares goes here

        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

        // others middlewares goes here
    ],
```